# Open File Chooser with one button and camera app with second button android webview kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I have two html buttons, one for file uploading of all types and other for open camera and capture image.

```
#File upload
<input type="file" >

#Open Camera
<input type="file" capture="camera" multiple accept="image/*">
```

I am using WebChromeClient to open file chooser in kotlin which is working fine and its uploading file to the server with below code.

```
    webView.setWebChromeClient(object: WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onShowFileChooser(webView:WebView, filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>, fileChooserParams:FileChooserParams):Boolean {
            if (file_permission() && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback

                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)                    
                intent.setType("*/*")
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE)
                return true
            }else
                return false
        }

    })
```

How do i integrate the camera opening option withing WebChromeClient so that it can detect the pressed html button and open intent accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, solved by sending console message and capturing it with onConsoleMessage() in kotlin

Comment: Another way is to use fileChooserParams.acceptTypes

Comment: Can you share your final MainActivity.kt?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.html), It has a method called [getTitle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.html#getTitle()).

From documentation

> Returns the title to use for this file selector. If null a default
>   title should be used.

Comment: But how would we know which button is pressed

Comment: @ArshDoda try to print the value of `getTitle()` method in the Logcat and let me know the result

Comment: in kotlin, i called it with fileChooserParams.title and it is empty in both cases

Comment: @try to give alt and title in the html input tag and see the logcat value

Comment: Its still empty

Comment: @ArshDoda Can you update the full HTML line you're using

Comment: '<div class="row">  
    <div class="question-row-list"> 
          <input data-elementid="ele_file_upload_id" type="file" title="file_upload" alt="file_upload" class="j_check_rule j_field_class file-field" placeholder="kkk" name="k" data-queskey="k-0"> 
    </div>
    <div class="question-row-list"> 
          <input data-elementid="ele_image_id" type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" class="j_check_rule j_field_class" placeholder="sd" name="ds" data-queskey="ds-0"> 
    </div>
</div>
'

Comment: @ArshDoda try to include NAME and ALT in the input tag. It should give you the title

Comment: yet its not getting for the first input in the android

Comment: Also, check `fileChooserParams.filenameHint` in the logcat

Comment: these all are for the intent not for the pressed button

Comment: @ArshDoda What value it is suggesting?

Comment: Its sending the null

Comment: i need to detect the pressed button of html in the webchromeclient  without using the javascript interface

Comment: @ArshDoda Then only left which you can rely on is `fileChooserParams.mode` which will give you [MODE_OPEN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.html#MODE_OPEN) , [MODE_OPEN_MULTIPLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.html#MODE_OPEN_MULTIPLE), [MODE_SAVE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.html#MODE_SAVE)

Comment: @ArshDoda If you're trying to load the file from ASSETS folder, then delete and reinstall the app.